# How to test for equality using pandas dataframes having written to csv

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having an issue with the following:

```py
d1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, {}], [4, 1, 0]])
d1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)])
d1.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4)])
d1 = d1.applymap(lambda l: np.nan if l == {} else l)
d1.to_csv("testing3452345.csv")
d2 = pd.read_csv("./testing3452345.csv", index_col=[0, 1], header=[0, 1])
d1.equals(d2)
```

Which is `False`, though I expect this to be `True`.

Looking at the data I have:

```
#print(d1)
     1       2
     1  2    3
1 2  1  2  3.0
2 3  3  4  NaN
  4  4  1  0.0


#print(d2)
     1       2
     1  2    3
1 2  1  2  3.0
2 3  3  4  NaN
  4  4  1  0.0
```

I'm not sure, but I think the issue might be that `np.nan` can't be tested for equality, so I have:

```py
pd.Series([np.nan])==pd.Series([np.nan]) # this is false
```

How should this be handled?

I thought that the following might work:

```py
d1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, {}], [4, 1, 0]])
d1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)])
d1.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4)])
d1 = d1.applymap(lambda l: "testing_value" if l == {} else l)
d1.to_csv("testing3452345.csv")
d2 = pd.read_csv("./testing3452345.csv", index_col=[0, 1], header=[0, 1])
d1.equals(d2)
```

But this still returns false.

Converting to dicts I have:

```
#d1.to_dict()
{(1, 1): {(1, 2): 1, (2, 3): 3, (2, 4): 4},
 (1, 2): {(1, 2): 2, (2, 3): 4, (2, 4): 1},
 (2, 3): {(1, 2): 3, (2, 3): 'testing_value', (2, 4): 0}}



#d2.to_dict()
{('1', '1'): {(1, 2): 1, (2, 3): 3, (2, 4): 4},
 ('1', '2'): {(1, 2): 2, (2, 3): 4, (2, 4): 1},
 ('2', '3'): {(1, 2): '3', (2, 3): 'testing_value', (2, 4): '0'}}
```

So perhaps this is something to do with the multiindex, I'm not too sure.

Comment: The columns of both dataframes need to have the same dtype. While looking at your converted dataframes (to dictionaries), I see some values in `d2` are strings instead of integers, as opposed to `d1`. Might that be the issue?

Comment: @ErikvandeVen they're the same `.dtypes`, but having been written to csv they're read as string, rather than mixed. I'm not sure how to deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this line after your `read_csv` function, should help fixing the problem.

```
d2.columns = d2.columns.set_levels([d2.columns.levels[1].astype(int), d2.columns.levels[1].astype(int)],level=[0,1])
```

The reason is that when reading the dataframe from the csv file, the  headers are set to strings instead of integers. With the line above we set those back to integers.

As far as I read, there isn't really a better solution for this.

Comment: still fails equality test though, so I don't think I can consider it as a solution, thanks tho

Comment: Odd... I tested it successfully on my local machine, else I wouldn't post this as a solution. I do see now it only works for your first piece of code, not your second one (the one where you changed np.nan to 'testing_value'. Will look into that